# Rabbitmq and Python NameError: global name problem

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm trying to send a JSON to Rabbitmq. 
this is my producer and it works properly:

```
import pika
import json

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('admin', '123')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('192.168.1.11',
                                       5672,
                                       '/',
                                       credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='myapp')

message = {'fname': 'test', 'lname': 'test'}

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='myapp',
                      body=json.dumps(message),
                      properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                         delivery_mode = 2,

                      ))
print(" [x] Sent %r" % message)

connection.close()
```

This is the receiver and it's not ok:

```
import pika
import time
import json

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('admin', '123')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('192.168.1.12',
                                       5672,
                                       '/',
                                       credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='myapp')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    myjson = json.loads(body)
    global fname
    global lname
    fname = myjson["fname"]
    lname = myjson["lname"]
    my_func(fname,lname)

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(queue='myapp',
                      auto_ack=True,
                      on_message_callback=callback)
channel.start_consuming()
def my_func(fname,lname):
    pass
```

when I run scripts 
the receiver show below problem :

NameError: global name 'my_func' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to this function in your receiver.py

> channel.start_consuming()

The function will block the program there and prevent it from seeing my_func(). On the other hand, the code analysis tool, e.g. pylint, may mostly likely fail to detect such error.

An easy solution is to change the code to

```py
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    myjson = json.loads(body)
    global fname
    global lname
    fname = myjson["fname"]
    lname = myjson["lname"]
    my_func(fname,lname)

def my_func(fname,lname):
    pass

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(queue='myapp',
                      auto_ack=True,
                      on_message_callback=callback)
channel.start_consuming()
```

A more complex solution is to create your own class or method and run start_consuming() in a asynchromized way.  Here is my example:

```py
def listen(self, exchange, routing, callback):
    self.ReceiveChannel = self.connection.channel()
    consumer_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.__consumer__, args=[exchange, routing, callback])
    consumer_thread.start()
```